# Two dimensional array with Smarty - fatal error cannot use object of type

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I am working on a PHP project and I am have multidimensional array and I am trying to loop through the array in Smarty to display it.

I am creating the following code in PHP

```
if (count($routeFields) > 1)
                {
                    $savedRoutes[$count] = new RouteDetails();

                    $savedRoutes[$count]->destination = $routeFields[DESTINATION];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->gateway = $routeFields[GATEWAY];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->genmask = $routeFields[GENMASK];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->flags = $routeFields[FLAGS];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->metric = $routeFields[METRIC];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->ref = $routeFields[REF];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->use = $routeFields[USEF];
                    $savedRoutes[$count]->iface = $routeFields[IFACE];

                    $count++;
                }
return $savedRoutes;

class RouteDetails
    {
        public $destination;
        public $gateway;
        public $genmask;
        public $flags;
        public $metric;
        public $ref;
        public $use;
        public $iface;
    }
```

Below is how I am calling my function and giving it to Smarty

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
                    $smarty->setTemplateDir("templates");

                    $routeManagement = new RouteManagement();
                    $result = $routeManagement->getRoutes();

                    $smarty->assign("routes", $result);

                    $smarty->display('routes.tpl');
```

Below is my Smarty template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Destination</td>
        <td>Gateway</td>
        <td>Genmask</td>
        <td>Flags</td>
        <td>Metric</td>
        <td>Ref</td>
        <td>Use</td>
        <td>Iface</td>
    </tr>
    {foreach from=$routes key=key item=item}
        <tr>
            <td>{$item.destination}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

I get the following error displayed:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type RouteDetails as array in
>   /var/www/html/RouteManagement/templates_c/06dfeb8eb18eac12fde3a6f643d7f25678e14aaf.file.routes.tpl.php
>   on line 46

Below is an output of $result

```
Array
(
    [0] => RouteDetails Object
        (
            [destination] => 192.168.1.0
            [gateway] => *
            [genmask] => 255.255.255.0
            [flags] => U
            [metric] => 0
            [ref] => 0
            [use] => 0
            [iface] => eth0
        )
)
```

Comment: try print_r($result) before assigning it to smarty to make sure the value is what you expect. Is it possible routeFields is also a 2 dimensional array? you are checking size as if you're expecting multiple arrays, but you're not going iterating in each one.

Comment: @DAB I've done a print_r, added it to my question, RouteDetails isn't multi-dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I get it. $item is an object, not an array. the smarty $item.destination means you are trying to access it like $item['destination']. Try $item->destination

Comment: Thanks I thought I'd tried that but apparently not. Thanks for your help